# Prove that the sequence always ends in $1$

Tags: number-theory

**Problem**

> Start with any natural number. If it is even, divide by two, if odd, multiply by three and add one. Repeat the same method on the new number, and the one after that, so on. Prove that you will always reach one no matter what you started with.

**Attempt**

We know that all powers of $2$ automatically work. Otherwise assume the number is not a power of $2$. We can represent such a number as $n = 2^a*b$ where $b$ is not a multiple of any power of $2$. After finite applications of dividing by $2$ we are left with $b = 3^{\alpha_1}*5^{\alpha_2} \cdots$. After that we apply $3n+1$ to get some even number. Then I get stuck. This question seems hard to solve since how do I deal with this case?

Comment: This is an open conjecture. What exactly is the point in publishing it here as a question?????

Comment: It is a legitimate question I am asking. I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: Well, you're asking for help solving something that nobody has solved as of yet, do you really expect to get an answer here?????

Comment: You could give me a hint or tip on how I should proceed. Just because it is an open problem doesn't automatically mean you shouldn't attempt it.

Comment: Of course I could, but it wouldn't get you anywhere, now would it? (Otherwise I would have posted the solution myself).

Comment: I don't know about the down-votes, I'm not the one who gave them, but I would assume that it upsets some of the users here to see a question without any significance contribution being posted.

Comment: Although I don't think there's a problem in asking it, you also shouldn't be surprised if it gets closed or downvotes (although I wouldn't do either).  A google search of "3n+1 problem" quickly identifies this as an open problem.  In that light, it seems unlikely that anyone could offer a worthwhile hint.  Feel free to approach the problem, but please consider that this problem will, in all likelihood, require a solid understanding of number theory, and there is not room in an answer to provide you with that.

Comment: Nobody knows what a proof will look like, so nobody knows what should be done next, in your situation. It's likely to be unsuccessful, largely because every known attempt has been unsuccessful, or only successful for a limited subset of starting numbers.

Comment: It's not a matter of willingness.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an open problem.

Answer (score 5):

This is known as the [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture). Paul Erdős offered $\$500$ for its solution, so it's fairly difficult.